# Bootstrap - Make list Icons size match my Logo's Size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

QUESTION - How can I make the List buttons on the right, match in size (or just fill the Nav Bar)

I have uploaded the site to here so you may see the code.

[Website.](http://duhuh.co.uk)

( I removed my previous question as it was badly worded and I did not have code to show, sorry )

Comment: Can you please show us you navigation bar code currently?  This will help us fix your code and answer your question. Thanks.

Comment: I would have done, It's just the html code would not be helpful as I believe (not pro at bootstrap) but they have everything in there massive  css file.

Comment: That's all right.  Looks like others are looking at the website's source code themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code to your css file or in inline block

```
@media (min-width: 979px){
    .navbar .nav li { line-height: 45px;}
}
```

Comment: `45px` makes navbar little bigger than on start. It should be `43px`

Comment: Is there a way of making this only apply if the nav bar is not minimised. It's hard to explain, but you can see when you open my website then make the page smaller the nav bar turns into a drop down to save space. Although now the dropdown menu is huge. Anyway to change this?

Comment: Here's a picture which explains better. http://imgur.com/WLJVWoL, - the new one is the one on the right.

Comment: Awesome man thanks. So is that saying only do this Ie, make line height 45px if the screen is more than 979px?

Comment: Yes. it will only make line height 45px if the screen width is more than 979px (which is for desktops and large screens).

Comment: Sorry if i am slightly grave digging this. But I cannot get this line to work in bootstrap 3. ANy change?